# Case statement based on the result Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Hi so I have a question regarding case statements and why certain statements dont work.

```
(Case WHEN LENGTH(input)<=5 THEN text LIKE '%'
  ELSE text = input)
```

When I did this, it didnt work and im still confused as to why. 
However the solution to this problem was

```
(Case WHEN LENGTH(input)<=5 THEN text LIKE Concat('%',input,'%')
  ELSE text = input END)
```

However My main question is below though I would like an answer to the above question and since they are identical I will leave it as one question.

I have a student who is still being reviewed for entering the school, however this school is german so i need to translate a few words for them since the system is in English

```
select s.fname, s.lastname, 
(Case when s.status like 'APPROVED' then s.status = 'Genehmigt'
when s.status like 'PENDING' then s.status = 'Anstehend.'
end) as Status
from Student
```

My results are giving me False in the status field so obviously im doing something wrong... 
And I know there are two types of case statement so am I using the recommended one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you have placed after `then`:

```
s.status = 'Genehmigt'
```

is not an assignment, it is a boolean expression, so it yields `true` or `false`. 
`s.status =` is just redundant.

```
select 
    fname, 
    lastname, 
    case when status = 'APPROVED' then 'Genehmigt'
    when status = 'PENDING' then 'Anstehend.'
    end as status
from student
```

Note that `like` with a string without wildcards on the right side should be a simple comparison.